# How to generate undirect edges by using the element of a Set in Spark

Tags: scala, set, scala-collections

I'm trying to generate some undirect edges using the elements of a `Set.Set(1, 4, 5),` for example, and the result must be like this:

```
(1,4)
(1,5)
(4,5)
```

Any solution will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to do it on dataframe or just on Set?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just on collection like Set or others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example using subset and filter

```
 val set = Set(1,4,5)

val result = set.subsets().map(_.toList).toList
```

Output:

```
List(1, 4)
List(1, 5)
List(4, 5)
```

If you want as a list of tuples then you can convert as

```
result.map(list => (list(0), list(1)))
```

Output:

```
(1,4)
(1,5)
(4,5)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you again from the bottom of my heart.it works ,but maybe like "set.subsets(2).map(_.toList).filter(_.size == 2).toList"

Comment: Welcome and thankyou as well. Yes subsets(2) works fine and no need to filter.

Comment: Yes,you're right.This approach in your comment is more convenient.